# Show the total amount of a column

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm currently making a game to teach myself PHP as I go. I've already progressed quite a bit but I'm stuck now at the statistics where I want to show how many of each player-class there currently is in the game.

Thanks everyone, finally managed to fix it - not in the way as answered but the answer did help me getting to a result!

Which is:

```
<?php
echo '<b>Current Classes in the Game :</b>' . '<br />';

$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE role='Warrior'");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0] . ' Warriors' . '<br />';

$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE role='Mage'");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0] . ' Mages' . '<br />';

$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE role='Priest'");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0] . ' Priests' . '<br />';

$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE role='Rogue'");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0] . ' Rogues' . '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: _I've tried the SUM functions and COUNT functions but none of them displays what I want._. Please show _this_ code. That is what is relevant here, not six lines of echoing static text.

Comment: I removed (fixed) from the title. Either post an answer, accept one or delete the question

Answer (score 1):

You need execute an sql query like this using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.query.php) :

```
select
    count(*) as nb,
    class
from
   yourTable
group by class
```